# String to date question 'style' not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, date

```
select convert (date,'27-07-2019',105)
```

results in 2019-07-27  while I would expect 'DD-MM-YYYY).

Why?

select convert (date,'27-07-2019',105)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are converting to a *date*, which is stored and presented using the internal representation and defaults of the server.

The default presentation is YYYY-MM-DD, which is not only a SQL Server standard but also an ISO standard for representing dates.  It is simply the best way to represent dates as a string (notably because it sorts correctly as a string).

If you want a bepoke string format, then convert the value to a string, not to a `date`.